# How to clone views in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a view and I need to re-render it in the same page.

If I call `.render()` again the first rendered is gone.

Cloning view object with `jQuery.extend()` has same result.

```
var cloneView = $.extend(true, {}, view);
$('#container').append(cloneView.render().el);
```

I cannot call `new View()` because there are various view classes.

How can I make a proper clone of a view?

Comment: Do you want to render the two pages to the same DOM element ?

Comment: I don't think so, my view just render a small `div`. If you mean `page` by `div` then yes, but not render into same DOM element.

Comment: Why not simply create a new instance of your view?

Comment: Creating a new instance is not convenient because the view class can be changed, dynamically.

Comment: http://ianstormtaylor.com/rendering-views-in-backbonejs-isnt-always-simple/

Answer (score 1):

You can't just clone your view and use it the way you want, because there's a lot of work done in the background, like :

- `cid` generation : unique id of your view in your application.
- `$el` generation : the view main DOM element
- `events` delegation : the view events delegation

So if you insist in cloning your view, I will suggest you to create a clone of it `var cloneView = $.extend(true, {}, view);` that do what exactly `new View` do.

And as `mu is too short` suggested, event `$.extend` won't work.

So the best way to do it, is to instantiate a `new View`

Comment: I don't think `$.extend` will know what to do with the view's `el`, events, contained models/collections and their events, ...

Comment: @muistooshort you're right, I'm just trying to convince him to create a new view.

Answer (score 0):

It is dangerous to go blindly clone any view. You need to check for subtle things like hard-coded IDs in the template and in the view, styles of the template when it's re-used in different locations,..etc.

I would suggest either:

1. Create a new instance of the view. (if you're sure it's safe to render the another instance simultaneously with the previous instance of the view on the same page).

`var my_view = new MyView({ el: $("#id") });`

1. Create a new view extending that view. (this is a better bet)

`CloneView = MyView.extend({
       // Stuff for CloneView
   });
 var my_view = new CloneView({ el: $("#id") });`